# Is there a way to access to pressure of a touch event in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, touch

On Android, we can access the pressure of an event using [getPressure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPressure%28%29), on iOS one can use the [force](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618110-force) property.  But can we access these event properties also when using dart/flutter?  If not, is there a work-around possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flutter you can use [ForcePressGestureRecognizer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/ForcePressGestureRecognizer-class.html)

The interpolation function should give you the raw device pressure.

Comment: Cool!    Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for "ForcePressGestureRecognizer" using GestureDetector Widget, check below links:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html#onForcePressStart

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/ForcePressGestureRecognizer-class.html